# In cesium, how do you dynamically update a label over time?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a label that associated with a billboard/marker in cesium that I want to 'update' over time. I tried using a setTimeout to increment a variable 'count' that I assign as the label to a marker... but it doesn't increment. Is there something special I need to be doing or am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update a label just by changing its text property.

```
entity.label.text = 'new text';
```

Here's a full example:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var image = new Image();
var entity;
image.onload = function() {
    entity = viewer.entities.add({
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
        billboard : {
            position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
            scaleByDistance : new Cesium.NearFarScalar(1.5e2, 5.0, 1.5e7, 0.5),
            image : image
        },
        label : {
            text : 'Label on top of scaling billboard',
            font : '20px sans-serif',
            showBackground : true,
            horizontalOrigin : Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.CENTER,
            pixelOffset : new Cesium.Cartesian2(0.0, -image.height),
            pixelOffsetScaleByDistance : new Cesium.NearFarScalar(1.5e2, 3.0, 1.5e7, 0.5)
        }
    });
    viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
};
image.src = '../images/facility.gif';

var counter = 0;
viewer.scene.postUpdate.addEventListener(function(){
    if(!Cesium.defined(entity)) {
        return;
    }
    counter += 0.04;
    if(Math.cos(counter) > 0){
        entity.label.text = "On";
    } else {
        entity.label.text = "Off";
    }
});
```

And [a live version](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=rVRRT9swEP4rXl6aaMVNCwUBpZooTJvEqDTYnvLiJufUwrUj22kpE/995yRtQ9A0TZpf4vN9d+f7fF/WzJC1gA0YckUUbMgMrChX9Gd1FvbSypxp5ZhQYHrRZaIStcYosWI5NEFf/T70Pu8B5YTbolFBqFZSswyRvFSpE1qFEfmVKIKrRqKrvgKtbAGWsiwLG4xfhbbCR5KL3f1mzDjcMXVMudGrG8gNgA2PzsZ0eHoyPD0965Pjc3o+HvkV9Q+5FkLKhWYmw2StEv+7jF82ZRKutzfCOqZSwLQthu+Bmc/MPCCGmXBIxzDqkzGN+8TvMW9Mx92ENecX9ffgem3BJFuAfN+ag2eHp727yo0tOl0QzasrCpUfWOl1SnJ8eh84iotnYpmyRxaM4F2YXerNNUufcqNL5al1poQOZqmNePGTJOdG5KJF85eOh85u7x9vv3fiC/EMcs65BfeWyv0rjcLYE3hUD94SRL500Z+zPPzz+xx33qf1BvX21YvAb5qJftF69ajDznx70OteINakKIEepYPKtgPOUiFRGDRHoveCS5FZV+k09kKrM9oUFFAcXPejyJgDr5zbNda5w6bQZcKD6pqREDz80PSYAUdVZ2GtwyhqT40BVxrVdNN0t7vCR7wDjU8u9wm/MbekqbZhg4jIlMRRK1tdgVbTSathvCJJMFdJsKtAQFogfw/h/BCDLEaXQT+YWLeVMK1PP4lVoY0jpZEhcupgVUhkxg4WZfoEjqa24n8y2AVNMrEmIrtKgs7fLglIKpm16OGllA/iBZJgOhkg/k2Y/7+hiOZrMJJtPWQ5nN7Vh5TSyQDN91FOa7lgppXxNw) on Sandcastle.